# Set and merge 'in-place': could it cause problems?

Tags: php

I have a static member variable and I set its values like so:

```
    private static $HTML_FILTER = [
        'div' => ['aria' => 1]
    ];

    public function __construct($allowed_html) {
        // Is the below dangerous?
        MyClass::$HTML_FILTER = array_merge_recursive(allowed_html, MyClass::$HTML_FILTER);

        // Should I instead do
        $temp = array_merge_recursive(allowed_html, MyClass::$HTML_FILTER);
        MyClass::$HTML_FILTER = $temp;
    }
```

Essentially I am interrogating a static array right before I (over)write it. Would this cause issues on certain versions of PHP or all?

Comment: Why do you think it will cause a problem in any version?

Comment: @NigelRen It just seems wrong/dangerous to write and interrogate  a static array in the same line of code. Which is why I asked here

Comment: As far as I know, this is more a problem when multiple threads are working on the same classes at the same time.  The problem there is that one thread could be updating whilst another is reading.  BUT that is another large issue which PHP solves by (generally) being single threaded, and your second code still wouldn't help.  So unless you are doing something with threaded PHP then I wouldn't worry.